# SSRS - Could not find schema information for the element

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Since the [October preview of SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) supports SSRS in Visual Studio 2015, I installed that and am trying to use it with my existing reports. I'm getting a bunch of errors, warnings, and messages, however. 61 messages exist that say the following:

```
Could not find schema information for the element  / 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner'.
```

I also get a warning for this report. Note that line 33 is just `<Fields>`.

```
[rsInvalidReportDefinition] The definition of this report is not valid or supported /
by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created /
with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed /
or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: Data at the root level is /
invalid. Line 33, position 28519.
```

The report code sections throwing these errors look like this:

```
<Field Name="PriorityId">
    <DataField>PriorityId</DataField>
    <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

The MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.rdlobjectmodel.field.typename%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that field gives that schema link as the correct link, but navigating to it shows it doesn't exist. I tried several others on [the server](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/), but they all return the same error with the relevant URL.

The reporting server is running SQL Server 2008 R2, hopefully being upgraded soon to 2014. How can I resolve these errors and (hopefully) therefore the build error?

Comment: You can't use a newer version of Visual Studio to build reports for an older version of SSRS.

Comment: @TabAlleman Do you possibly have a source for this? [The information I've found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674.aspx) on MSDN seems to indicate that it is possible.

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I just know this from experience.   The article you reference, to me, is saying that reports can be upgraded, but assumes that the SSRS server will similarly be upgraded.  At least that's the way I read it.   See my answer here for a lengthy description:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086849/can-a-ssis-2012-package-be-deployed-to-sql-server-2008-r2