# Upgraded SSIS package from BIDS 2005 to SSDT 2015, trying to run it gives "cannot access property IsExternal" error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, bids

The upgrade went through without issues, the project builds properly, all the connections test correctly, etc. However, after starting the package (which consists of several Transfer SQL Server Object Tasks), the first two succeed and the third fails with:

> [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task] Error: Execution failed with the following error: "Cannot access property IsExternal.This property is not available on SQL Server 2008 R2.".

Is there a way to get a more detailed error, if nothing else? As is, I don't even know where it's trying to find this property.

Comment: Am I to understand that you upgraded your package to 2015, and are attempting to run it on a 2008R2 server?

Comment: Yes. For what it's worth, the same thing happened on the SQL 2014 instance.

Comment: Packages developed in SSDT 2015 are produced to run on SQL 2016.   They are not expected to be able to work on any earlier version of SQL Server.   `IsExternal` is undoubtedly a property that SQL Server 2016 will recognize, but was not in use prior.   See my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086849/can-a-ssis-2012-package-be-deployed-to-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered or editing it for more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages developed with SSDT will not work on any server on or before SQL Server 2008 R2. For SQL Server 2008 R2 and prior use BIDS. I know it's a pain but at least SSDT is now readily available (included with VS 2013+) compared to BIDS (if you have modern servers).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft data tools are backward compatible up to certain point. Visual Studio 2015 only supports SQL 2012/2014/2016. You can adjust target SQL Server version using project configuration properties.
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOWwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Switching the version of SQL Server that SSIS/Visual Studio targets to the same version as your SQL Server may fix the issue. It did for me!

To change the target SQL Server version in Visual Studio:

1. Right click your SSIS project in the Solution Explorer, and select Properties
2. In the left-hand side menu in the Properties dialog, select Configuration Properties -> General
3. Change the "TargetServerVersion" to the same version as your SQL Server

I was running SSIS on Visual Studio 2015, against a server running SQL Server 2014. SSIS looked to be originally targeting SQL Server 2017, and failed with the same error as OP. I switched Visual Studio to target SQL Server 2014, and then the task ran successfully.