# SSIS Package fails to load - VS 2013

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I created SSIS Package in VS 2013, however my target server is SQL Server 2008 R2. So after completing the development, when i tried scheduling SQL Job to call the package using SSMS (SQL server 2008 R2), i got the error while loading the package :

> "TITLE: SSIS Execution Properties ------------------------------  The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.   ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:  The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.   ------------------------------ BUTTONS:  OK ------------------------------ ".

Looks like they both are incompatible. Can anyone suggest an alternative to deploy the package ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/) for finding the right version of VS and SSIS. Looks like you need VS 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a SSIS 2012 package be deployed to SQL Server 2008 R2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086849/can-a-ssis-2012-package-be-deployed-to-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed using VS 2013 and if you are using Project deployment model (not supported in 2008 R2). You can convert it to Package deployment model.

Backwards Compatibility doesn't work in VS for Integration services as mentioned by @NickyvV in comments.

You can try to open and save/redevelop the converted packages using BIDS (VS for SQL 2008 R2).

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** develop SSIS package for SSIS 2008R2 on VS 2013. VS 2013 supports packages for SSIS 2014 only.
For SSIS 2008R2 you have to use BIDS from SQL 2008 or VS 2008. Unfortunately, you will have to develop package from scratch, backporting from SSIS 2012+ DTSX format to 2008 is not supported.

Comment: yes.. thanku both.. guess i will develop the package again in BIDS 2008 that comes with SQL server 2008.. which will work for both sql server 2008 and sql server 2008 r2